# Is there any programmatic way to remote desktop / vnc from mac to mac? Is there any native support?

Tags: macos, vnc

My end goal is to be able to remotely trigger a remote desktop / vnc login. I'm not very familiar with OS X, so pardon my ignorance. Is there any native support for this? Perhaps I would be best off using a script to initiate the remote login? Also, from my brief readings, I think I might need to create an Authorization plugin. Is that something to be expected?

Thanks a lot guys. Please let me know if I can clarify more.

Comment: Your title says "mac to mac". Your question and tags bring up iOS. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should post on [Apple StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) then did you take a look to [Screen Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11150)? Finally, on your title you said mac2mac and the you talk about iOs... Give us more informations :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me that way. Sorry, I guess I should say OS X instead of iOS. I'm googling this Shared screen api now. It says iOS, but is there a similar way to this with OS X apps. It seems to just put your screen on the monitor. I'm looking for a full remote session where the user could then use the mouse and keyboard inputs. Do you know if this is supported/feasible?

Comment: @Chad this is a full remote solution, I use it every day

Comment: Okay, I came upon, the terminal commands. Seems very simple/handy. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

All you should have to do is open System Preferences and go to Sharing. There, you activate `Remote Login`, which enables login through SFTP and SSH. Both should work with a VNC client. I'm not sure what you mean with "remotely triggering" the login, but if you want to send scripts from another machine, `Remote Apple Events` in the same prefpane might be what you are looking for.